# Pentesting from a virtual machine, hiding the host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I want to install Kali Linux as a virtual machine in VirtualBox for pentesting wireless routers and network hosts. I want to hide my host OS, which is Windows 8, so that other machines see my computer as a Linux computer only.

What kind of network connection do I need to configure in the VM? Bridge adapter? How should I configure it to hide the host?

Comment: Hiding the host will involve some configuration in Windows. That part is off-topic here.

Comment: I think what you need is Bridged adapter. The virtual NIC is bridged to a physical NIC in this case. In this case, both the guest and host will be treated as separate machines in a network. \

Comment: You can't use a virtualised OS to do "Wifi pen-testing".  VirtualBox will provide your Linux VM with a virtual WIRED adapter, no matter whether you bridge or NAT it.

Comment: wifi + bridged something is a usually a no-go ( some details there https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header ). The only way is to have somehow the wifi device "passed through" to the VM so that it isn't visible/usable anymore on the host and thus does not involve any network handling by the hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change network type of host machine to Bridge and Virtual machine(Linux) to NAT.

Here is how to setup bridge network on host machine

[Bridge on linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configuring-bridging-in-debian-linux/)

or

[Bridge on Windows](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10)

As mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/227505/what-is-the-difference-between-nat-bridged-host-only-networking)

> **NAT:** Just like your home network with a wireless router, the VM will
>   be assigned in a separate subnet, like 192.168.6.1 is your host
>   computer, and VM is 192.168.6.3, then your VM can access outside
>   network like your host, but no outside access to your VM directly,
>   it's protected.
>
> **Bridged:** Your VM will be in the same network as your host, if your
>   host IP is 172.16.120.45 then your VM will be like 172.16.120.50. It
>   can be accessed by all computers in your host network.

In this way only NAT will be visible in ip ranges unless you use [Nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) to discover host